# How can I hide asp controls or div tags that are inside a asp:GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview, ascx

I have this `ASP:GridView` and I cant seem to be able to declare the asp controls or div tags inside this `ASP:GridView` in  my codebehind ascx file.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="siteMembersView" AllowPaging="True" 
            ShowHeader="False" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="membership-gridview" Width="100%" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

             //content

            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am trying to put `Mydiv.Visible = false` and `LinkButton.Visible = False`
But it cant find the IDs. I am using `runat="server"`. I think the problem is that its inside the GridView beacuse I tried to put it outside the GridView and it worked perfectly.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use the FindControl method to access your controls, then you can apply the logic to toggle the visibility of each:

[How to find control in TemplateField of GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873973/how-to-find-control-in-templatefield-of-gridview)

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl myDiv;
    LinkButton myLinkButton;

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        myDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("myDiv") 
            as HtmlGenericControl;
        myDiv.Visible = false;

        myLinkButton = (LinkButton )e.Row.FindControl("myLinkButton") 
            as LinkButton;
        myLinkButton.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @IrishChieftan is correct.  You cannot hide a control that is nested inside a GridView, DataGrid, Repeater, or other control whose DataSource binds to a collection.  You have to find the target control in the outer control's ItemDataBound event and then show or hide it conditionally based on whatever logic you like.  Be sure your code checks to make sure "myDiv" (from the above answer) is not null before setting a value on it.  Otherwise if someone else changes the control's ID, you'll get a null reference exception.

Comment: For some reason this code is not working I have my linkbutton ID inside the FindControl parameter. Do the method name need to be specific to something?

Comment: Can you show us the control's markup in the template and your version of my code sample?

Comment: @IrishChieftan wrote you an event handler.  You need to bind an event to it, or it will not fire.  Add OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" in the start tag of your GridView control.