# Get the cell value of a GridView row

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I am using the GridView - `AutoGenerateSelectButton = "True"` to select the row in order to get the Column 1 cell value.

I have tried:

```
GridViewRow row = dgCustomer.SelectedRow;
TextBox1.Text = "Cell Value" + row.Cells[1].Text + "";
```

And it writes the "Cell Value" but nothing else.

I finally was able to get the number of the row (index) but not the cell value.

```
GridViewRow row = dgCustomer.SelectedRow;
TextBox1.Text = row.RowIndex.ToString();
```

I have tried:

```
TextBox1.Text = dgCustomer.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
```

and still returns the index row.

Any other suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: Trial and error. Try changing the index until you get the desired result. Cells[1], Cells[2], etc...

Comment: I tried to Cells[6] and all give me the row index and not the value of the cell. Any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post some code here so we know what type of cell you are trying extract the value from?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try changing your code to

```
// Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
GridViewRow row = dgCustomer.SelectedRow;

// And you respective cell's value
TextBox1.Text = row.Cells[1].Text
```

**UPDATE:** (based on my comment)
If all what you are trying to get is the primary key value for the selected row then an alternate approach is to set

`datakeynames="yourprimarykey"`

for the gridview definition which can be accessed from the code behind like below.

```
TextBox1.Text = CustomersGridView.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Do you really have value in `Cells[1]`?

Comment: I am assuming that I have a value since is column 1.

Comment: Not sure why all cell values are empty for you. Optionally you can set `datakeynames="yourprimarykey"` for the gridview and access the key value like `TextBox1.Text = CustomersGridView.SelectedValue.ToString()`

Comment: Dennis is working :) yeah I am soooooo excited please change the previous answer so I can give you the credit. OMG you have no idea how much stress you just took off my shoulders!!!

Comment: @Lily Glad it's working now. I've updated my answer with the alternate code.

Answer (score 8):

## Windows Form Iteration Technique

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Selected)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            int index = cell.ColumnIndex;
            if (index == 0)
            {
                value = cell.Value.ToString();
                //do what you want with the value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a Window's form response, not ASP.net which is what a Gridview is

Comment: @Nick Roberts It helped me for Windows form. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use a HiddenField inside template field use FindControl to find this field.

ie:

ASPX

```
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFname" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FileName") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code behind

```
protected void gvAttachments_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv1 = (GridView)sender;
        GridViewRow gvr1 = (GridViewRow)gv1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        //get hidden field value and not directly from the GridviewRow, as that will be null or empty!
        HiddenField hf1 = (HiddenField)gvr1.FindControl("hfFname");
        if (hf1 != null)
        {
           ..
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Cell[0]`? Remember indexes start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Dennis R answer above ... 
This will get the value based on the Heading Text (so you don't need to know what column...especially if its dynamic changing).

Example setting a session variable on SelectedIndexChange.

```
    protected void gvCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int iCustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(Library.gvGetVal(gvCustomer, "CustomerID"));
        Session[SSS.CustomerID] = iCustomerID;
    }

public class Library
{
    public static string gvGetVal(GridView gvGrid, string sHeaderText)
    {
        string sRetVal = string.Empty;
        if (gvGrid.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (gvGrid.SelectedRow != null)
            {
                GridViewRow row = gvGrid.SelectedRow;
                int iCol = gvGetColumn(gvGrid, sHeaderText);
                if (iCol > -1)
                    sRetVal = row.Cells[iCol].Text;
            }
        }
        return sRetVal;
    }

    private static int gvGetColumn(GridView gvGrid, string sHeaderText)
    {
        int iRetVal = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < gvGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (gvGrid.Columns[i].HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == sHeaderText.ToLower().Trim())
            {
                iRetVal = i;
            }
        }
        return iRetVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours. I found that when i use the `BoundField` tag in GridView to show my data. The `row.Cells[1].Text` is working in:

```
GridViewRow row = dgCustomer.SelectedRow;
TextBox1.Text = "Cell Value" + row.Cells[1].Text + "";
```

But when i use `TemplateField` tag to show data like this:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="料號">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Part_No" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Part_No")%>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="bhead" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="bbody" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

The `row.Cells[1].Text` just return null. I got stuck in this problem for a long time. I figur out recently and i want to share with someone who have the same problem my solution. Please feel free to edit this post and/or correct me.

My Solution:

```
Label lbCod = GridView1.Rows["AnyValidIndex"].Cells["AnyValidIndex"].Controls["AnyValidIndex"] as Label;
```

I use `Controls` attribute to find the `Label` control which i use to show data, and you can find yours. When you find it and convert to the correct type object than you can extract text and so on. Ex:

```
string showText = lbCod.Text;
```

Reference:
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242943/7786739)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an integer value in named column, so I did the below:

```
int index = dgv_myDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

int id = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_myDataGridView["ID", index].Value)
```

The good thing about this is that the column can be in any position in the grid view and you will still get the value.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In ***SelectedIndexChanged*** event value from a selected row/cell can be found as below :

```
string id = gvLR.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.FromCellNumber();
```

In ***RowCommand*** event value from a hidden cell can be found as below:

```
HiddenField hdnProgramId = (((e.CommandSource as 
LinkButton).Parent.FindControl("SystemId")) as HiddenField);
string id = hdnProgramId.Value;
```

In ***SelectedRowDelete*** event value from any cell can be got as follow:

```
string _fileEntryId = gvLR.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
```

For **any/all** row in the Gridview as follow:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows) 
{
  if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   { 
   string _FileEntryId = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("SystemId")).Value;
   string kk=row.Cells[3].Text; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string id;
foreach (GridViewRow rows in grd.Rows)
{
   TextBox lblStrucID = (TextBox)rows.FindControl("grdtext");
   id=lblStrucID.Text
}
```