# how to stop/disable onclientclick() event of linkbutton in gridview when gridview is disabled?(Its not normal link button, it is in gridview)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my website, once an application is submitted. The complete application gets disabled, but when i click on Delete link button in gridview, it is firing onClientClick() event, even it is also disabled.

I want to stop/disable onclientclick() event of linkbutton in gridview when gridview is disabled?

Comment: How are you disabling the complete application on client side/server side?

Comment: @ Anil Kumar- we are disabling it from server side.

Comment: then you should be setting  linkButton.OnClientClick = null as mentioned in How to completely disable the link button? [duplicate]

Comment: anil, can u please give an example of it. How can i access linkbutton in gridview...?? and that too with OnClientClick()..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873973/how-to-find-control-in-templatefield-of-gridview

Comment: Thanks Anil Kumar. I got the logic @  
your given link. Its working fine now.