# Accessing user control elements from parent

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to access the user control elements such as textbox from parent control.Its showing the error " 'user control' element does not exist in the current context".I cannot access the user control elements??

Comment: go through https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess, I think you are trying to get the scope of any control (textbox) which is located inside any other server side view like GridView? You can try this way:

```
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);
        TextBox _selectedStorageLocation = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtName");
```

Take a look at this [thread as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873973/how-to-find-control-in-templatefield-of-gridview).