# How to Multiply two columns on a gridview and display it in the third?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How would I multiply 2 columns and display it in the third column? I want to multiply Price and the input value of quantity and display it in `lblItemTotal`. I was thinking about adding a update button so that all the item totals could get updated when clicked. Here's my gridview code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblItemTotal" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: With JavaScript, bind to key up event on the quantity column field, and update third column if you want to see it in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the controls first in order to extract their values. 
Maybe this link can help you: 
[How to find control in TemplateField of GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873973/how-to-find-control-in-templatefield-of-gridview).

If you click on the update button, you can loop through every row in the gridview and find the "txtQuantity" and "lblPrice" controls using the method described in the link, multiply them, and then set the result using the text property of "lblItemTotal" (which you also found using the method described in the link).

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality should ideally be done on the client(in javascript).Here's a complete working example, just copy and paste as is into your solution and it will work:

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class GridTwo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<OrderLineItem> lineItems = new List<OrderLineItem>();
        lineItems.Add(new OrderLineItem { Price = 10.00M, Quantity = 0, ItemTotal = 0.00M });
        lineItems.Add(new OrderLineItem { Price = 100.00M, Quantity = 0, ItemTotal = 0.00M });
        lineItems.Add(new OrderLineItem { Price = 5.00M, Quantity = 0, ItemTotal = 0.00M });

        GridView1.DataSource = lineItems;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

public class OrderLineItem
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemTotal { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $(".QuantityClass").on('change keyup paste', function () {

                //Ctrl+Shift+J in Google Chrome to bring up the console which allows you to debug javascript
                debugger;

                var textBox = this;
                var quantity = $(textBox).val();
                var tableRows = $(textBox).parent().parent().children();

                if (quantity != "") {
                    var price = tableRows[0].children[0].innerHTML;

                    var itemTotal = price * quantity;

                    tableRows[2].children[0].innerHTML = itemTotal;
                }
                else
                    tableRows[2].children[0].innerHTML = "";
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" CssClass="QuantityClass" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblItemTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**
[image: Multiply two columns on a grid view]