# Show a button based on the value of a field in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have two buttons (btn_Out and btn_In). I want to display btn_Out if the value of field *Active* in an SQL table called *Machines* is True (1) and display btn_In if the value of *Active* is set to False (0).

Every row in the data in the gridview may have a different Active flag and so the button needs to reflect this. The button will change the active flag from 0 to 1 and vice versa (i have this working!).

I am using a gridview and my code is as follows:

ASP.NET

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_In" runat="server" Text="Set in Scope" CommandName="Update" CssClass="Button" />
</ItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_Out" runat="server" Text="Set in Scope" CommandName="Update" CssClass="Button" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

C#:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{        
    sda.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Open();
    con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select [active] from [ALLMACHINES].[dbo].[Machines] where [serial_number] = @serialNumber";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial_Number", serialNumber);
    int Active = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

    if (Active == 1)
    {
        btn_In.Visible = false;
        btn_Out.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (Active == 0)
    {
        btn_Out.Visible = false;
        btn_In.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

My aspx.net page doesn't like that I've used the buttons in the if and else if statement and won't compile! Any tips would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Canyou put complete code, with method names and all.

Comment: Where is your code? You have to do this on PageLoad.

Comment: you need to be familiar with how PostBacks and Rendering work.. you need to get at the attributes of the button to do this also in C# code behind what event does this code reside in..?

Comment: You should get an exception from sql-server because you are using `@Serial_Number` as parameter name but it's actually `@SerialNumber`. Do you have a `Try...Catch{//ignore}` that swallows this exception?

Comment: I think you are in wrong way, if you using this code withing `foreach`, you are attacking to the server. I said `foreach`, because you need that to access `buttons`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set the visibility directly in the buttons? Then you don't need `OnRowDataBound`

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_In" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Active")) == true %>' Text="Set in Scope" CommandName="Update" CssClass="Button" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btn_Out" Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Active")) == false %>' runat="server" Text="Set in Scope" CommandName="Update" CssClass="Button" />
```

Also works with strings etc if your flag is not a Boolean.

```
Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Active").ToString() == "1" %>'
```

Comment: Thank you - i found that this was the easiest and quickest way of doing it without having to change a lot of code!!

Answer (score 1):

Best method to dynamically change the gridview cell value is `onrowdatabound` event. May following code help you out:

**Aspx Page**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">  
                <Columns>  
                    <asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Lable ID="lblstus" runat="server" Text="#Eval("active")" Visible=false>
</ItemTemplate>  
               ... otherfields you wanted to add
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_In" runat="server" Text="Set in Scope" CommandName="Update" CssClass="Button"  />
 <asp:Button ID="btn_Out" runat="server" Text="Set in Scope" CommandName="Update" CssClass="Button"  />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField> 
                </Columns>  
            </asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           Lable lblstus = e.Row.FindControl("lblstus") as Lable;
          Button btn_Out = e.Row.FindControl("btn_Out") as Button;
        Button btn_In = e.Row.FindControl("btn_In") as Button;
           if(lblstus.Text == "1")
            {
btn_In.Visible = false;
            btn_Out.Visible = true;
        } else {
            btn_In.Visible = false;
            btn_Out.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have two buttons (btn_Out and btn_In).

You have 2 buttons in *each* row, and each row may have different value, that is you can't select that value only once as you did in your code. Instead, read about RowDataBound event ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem(v=vs.110).aspx), [How to find control in TemplateField of GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873973/how-to-find-control-in-templatefield-of-gridview), etc), get rid of your current code and do something similar to this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Retrieve the underlying data item. In this example
        // the underlying data item is a DataRowView object. 
        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        // Retrieve the state value for the current row. 
        String flag = rowView["active"].ToString();

        Button btn_Out = e.Row.FindControl("btn_Out") as Button;
        Button btn_In = e.Row.FindControl("btn_In") as Button;

        if (flag == "1") {
            btn_In.Visible = false;
            btn_Out.Visible = true;
        } else {
            btn_In.Visible = false;
            btn_Out.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```