# How to find HTML Label element on Gridview with C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, label

I have a gridview and it has HTML label element like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="2%">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <label id="test" runat="server" title="" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

I want to change title attribute of label on C#. I tried this code below bu it did not work.

```
Label test= (Label)GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].FindControl("test");
test.ToolTip= "abc";
```

Am I missing something or did something wrong? I know I can use `<asp:Label>` but I don't want to

Comment: There was an article on this issue. maybe it will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873973/how-to-find-control-in-templatefield-of-gridview

Comment: try adding the name attribute to the label and then use  `var labels = document.getElementByName('test');`.  this will return an array.  You can then just use the row number to get it...  `var label = labels[rownum];`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I want to get that label on server side with C#.